# Game does not start (0xc000007b error)

Tags: rome-total-war

“Rome: Total War” does not start. Every time I try to start it, I always get the `0xc000007b` error message.

I have tried several solutions, but none of them has worked so far. I have tried [these](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/31bwpk/getting_this_application_was_unable_to_start/) solutions and I have also tried the `aio runtime package`, but nothing has worked so far. I have restarted my computer and installed the game several times. But it still does not work.

My machine runs a Windows 7 64 bit version.

Comment: Where'd you get the game?  Was it Steam?

Comment: No, it is an older version on CD.

Comment: What's your hardware? Are your drivers up to date? The error can as well be caused by wrong graphic drivers or unsupported hardware (like on-board GPUs).

Comment: I don’t know every hardware component. I would have to look them up. But updating the driver for my graphics card might help. I will give it a try.

Comment: have you tried running in compatibility mode using a different version of windows?

Comment: Yes, I have. I have tried pretty much everything on the list, but I have not installed windows from anew, yet. This, however, will only be the **last** option for me.

Answer (score -1):

There is [an elaborate reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/31bwpk/getting_this_application_was_unable_to_start/) post that offers a variaty of solutions. They are as followed :

> here may be multiple reasons as to why you might receive 0xc00007b
>   error when trying to run an application on a windows machine.
>   0xc000007b error usually comes from mixing up 32bit environment with
>   64bit one. For example 32bit application loads a 64bit dll causing
>   0xc000007b error.
>
> Solution 1 In most cases it's .NET framework causing issues. This can easily fixed by re-installing latest .NET framework from [link]
>
> Solution 2 Re-install the application that you are trying to run. It sounds simple but the application data files could be corrupt or
>   missing. This could be caused by a installation that did not complete
>   successfully or by a virus.
>
> Solution 3 Running the application as an administrator could fix this error. Right click on the program shortcut or program .exe file,
>   then click on Properties, and on the Compatibility tab. Check the Run
>   this program as an administrator box, and click on OK
>
> Solution 4 Restart your computer as some applications require restart after installation to function properly.
>
> Solution 5 Run Windows update as it can provide application fixes and updates. Furthermore it installs missing drivers and updates the
>   outdated ones like graphic card drivers. Windows 7 / 8 / 8.1 users
>   need to search for "windows update". select all important and optional
>   updates and click on the "install updates" button. If you use Windows
>   XP navigate navigate to Windows Update by choosing Start > All
>   Programs > Windows Update. When the scan is complete,Click the Review
>   and Install Updates link. Finally press the "install now" button.
>
> Solution 6 manually update the application if possible.
>
> Solution 7 re-install Microsoft Visual C++ runtime from [x32 link] or [x64 link]
>
> Solution 8 re-install DirectX [link]
>
> Solution 9 Many times hard disk problems can be repaired using the chkdsk command. If you are using windows 7 press the start button in
>   bottom left corner of your screen. If you are using windows 8 / 8.1
>   press the windows key .Search for "cmd" and Right click it and select
>   "Run as administrator". Windows XP users Click on start > run. In the
>   Run box, type in "cmd" in the box. A CMD window should appear. In that
>   window you can just type it as you see "chkdsk c: /f /r". If you have
>   more then one drive or partition, you will need to tell it the disk
>   (chkdsk d: /f /r). If it is the primary windows disk c: it will ask
>   you to schedule it for next boot. When you restart, it will do a
>   chkdsk for you before even getting to the login screen.
>
> Solution 10 This solution only works for a 64-bit system. It requires replacing files is system32 directory so be careful. Only
>   attempt this solution if you are confident and if other solutions have
>   failed. When Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Package is not
>   properly configured it may cause 0xc00007b error. Firstly download the
>   zip file [link] and decompress it. Reboot in safe mode and go to
>   C:\Windows\System32. copy all files included in the zip package
>   (mfc100.dll, mfc100u.dll, msvcr100.dll, msvcp100.dll and
>   msvcr100_clr0400.dll) to C:\Windows\System32 replacing the current
>   ones. After that reboot in normal mode.

If all the solutions above haven't worked i would consider backing up data and performing a clean install of windows

Comment: I have already linked this post in my question. Nothing has helped so far.

Comment: Sorry I read over that, Have you tried a clean install

Comment: I have tried to install the game several times. But that did not help.